# Reading line from Word document

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating an Excel VBA script to send reports via email. I made the following function to validate an attachment before including it on the email.

The function below will open the word document, check if the first line matches a customer ID and return a bool.

It works, however, when I read the data from Word, it includes some hidden quotes into the text.

While both strings are 123a, when I paste them into another text editor, I see the one i read from Word as "123a". If i print them using MsbBox, both are equal to 123a.

```
Function ValidateAttachment(attachmentURL As String, customerID As String) As Boolean

    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oWdoc As Word.Document

    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Set oWdoc = oWord.Documents.Open(attachmentURL)

    If StrComp(oWdoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text, customerID, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ValidateAttachment = True
    Else
        ValidateAttachment = False
    End If

    oWord.Quit

    Set oWord = Nothing

    Exit Function
End Function
```

This is what i see when i write both results into regular cells. Even I i make a simple formula IF to check for equality, it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Shooting in the dark, but I'm perplexed. How about you first assign oWdoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text to a variable and then do the compare.

Comment: Same output, and what makes this even weirder is that, if i insert a breakpoint and hover the variable, I see the correct value

Comment: How about If oWdoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = customerID Then...

Comment: That was my first try. Same result. Maybe one way aroud it would be to have the vba paste it into notepad, and then copy it back to Excel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to deal with the invisible quotes.

Using this did the trick:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean()
```

And here is the final code:

```
Function ValidateAttachment(attachmentURL As String, customerID As String) As Boolean

    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oWdoc As Word.Document

    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Set oWdoc = oWord.Documents.Open(attachmentURL)

    Dim x As String
    x = "123a"

     Application.Sheets(1).Columns(3).Rows(2) = Replace(oWdoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text, Chr(34), "")

    If StrComp(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(oWdoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text), customerID, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ValidateAttachment = True
    Else
        ValidateAttachment = False
    End If

    oWord.Quit

    Set oWord = Nothing

    Exit Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
If StrComp(Replace(oWdoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text,chr(34),""), customerID, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
```

Comment: Same output, pasting the result into notepad returns 123a
"123a
"
While Excel and MsgBox Shows 123a